# Full Calendar is not showing events from JSON source

Tags: jquery, json, ruby-on-rails-3, fullcalendar

I've read the entire documentation on Full Calendar and still I cannot render anything from a JSON source.  I'm running Rails 3.2 and when I preview my JSON source with Google's Developer Tools I see the correctly formatted JSON objects and a Header with a Status Code of 200 and an Accept: application/json.  I'm calling Full Calendar like so:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({events: '/events'});
```

If I declare a single JSON object and then render it by itself it renders fine like so:

```
var event = {
  "title": "Event 1",
  "start": "1363794900",
  "end": "1363794900",
  "url": "/events/4"
}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event);
```

**EDIT 1**
In the events controller, index.json.erb looks like this:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  {
    "title": "<%= event.name %>",
    "start": "<%= event.from.strftime("%s") %>",
    "end": "<%= event.to.strftime("%s") %>",
    "url": "<%= event_path(event) %>"
  }
<% end %>
```

and it's returning the following:

```
{
"title": "Matts Party",
"start": "1363794900",
    "end": "1363794900",
    "url": "/events/4"
}
{
    "title": "Mateuszs Party",
    "start": "1363795440",
    "end": "1363795440",
    "url": "/events/5"
}
{
    "title": "Johns Party",
    "start": "1363799400",
    "end": "1363799400",
    "url": "/events/6"
}
{
    "title": "Mikes Party",
    "start": "1364054040",
    "end": "1364054040",
    "url": "/events/3"
}
```

Comment: please post your json response.

Comment: Sorry @Nix, by json response do you mean the json objects that come through?

Comment: I want to see what /events is returning from the server.

Comment: I'm assuming there is a trailing } that was just accidentally left out  ?  Also is this wrapped in something?  Bc, that isn't valid json.

Comment: ok thanx, figured out the correct JSON format.

Comment: So the issue was malformed JSON ?

Answer (score 7):

The JSON code that your script generate is not correct. 
You can try to validate it here: http://jsonlint.com/
Paste your generated JSON code to see the issues.

Your structure is like this:
{...}{...}{...}

Should be modified to this:
[{...},{...},{...}]